# Tips on language or environment with better results in teaching numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods

I am preparing my first course on Numerical Methods for Electrical Engineering and would like to collect feedback from colleagues with experience in the subject, about which language or environment has generated more positive results in relation to student learning. MATLAB / Octave?, Python? C / C++? It would be interesting to use the R? Sorry if the question is outside the scope of the site.

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

## Octave

- Gentle learning curve-- easier to start using, than C, FORTRAN or even Python. Allows you to focus your curriculum on the concepts and not the minutiae.
- Uses an interpreted programming model-- students receive feedback quickly. No compile/link. Rapid feedback also encourages students to explore concepts freely.
- It works very well with the command line interface. Simple is good.
- Runs on many operating systems.
- Many, many scripts available freely.
- Large community that supports MATLAB and Octave. Help is never far away.
- Installation is very simple.
- Many high-level numerical function are built-in, so to speak. You can choose to let your students use them, or not. It will depend on the curriculum.
- Octave is free and works very well.

The only thing I miss is IDE integration with a debugger.

Check with the other faculty. They might have an opinion about what tool sets are appropriate for the class.

Answer (score 0):

Environments with a Read-Execute-Print-Loop are far, far better than anything which requires a compiler.  C and C++ (and Java for that matter) impose some intellectual overheads that may not be helpful.

In all cases (Matlab, Python, R) the basic rules of Floating Point arithmetic are absolutely essential.

It seems like (almost) every week someone posts yet another question here on why

```
>>> 555*(1/.555)
999.9999999999999
```

happens in Python (or Java or C).

Please don't allow your students to ask this question here.

Comment: Thanks, Dont worry about this question :)

Comment: While I'm no more anxious to see that question than you, I'm fully of the opinion that *most* people don't ask it to be malicious. It gets asked often because it's a common misunderstanding. To say "don't allow your students to ask this question here" makes it sound as if the question itself is bad. Rather, I would have said: "make sure that your students understand how floating-point arithmetic works so they won't be confused when the results aren't quite what they expect".

Comment: @Cody Gray: "malicious"?  Who suggested it was malice?  It's partly ignorance, but it is more unwarranted, thoughtless assumptions.  But I don't think I suggested it was malice.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you suggested it was malicious. Read the rest of my comment. Perhaps I should have said that they don't ask it to be *"annoying"*. Either way, I think your choice of phrasing for the last sentence is more condemnatory of those students than they deserve. It isn't "thoughtless assumptions"; what seems like second nature to experienced programmers probably wasn't really that obvious. Lots of students now are also familiar with pocket calculators (particularly those that use CAS), and expect that a computer would be *more* advanced, rather than what appears to be less.

Comment: Cody Gray: You said "malicious".  It wasn't an "implication" or a "suggestion".  It was a statement you made.   I was asking where you got that from.  Which word?  Which phrase?  It seems hard to hand-wring over nuances when there's a clear statement like "malicious".  None of which really matters.  Your point is that "understanding" is the important part.